# Why don't Funcs accept more than 16 arguments?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, functional-programming, arguments

Since Javascript is the language that I am the most proficient at, I am familiar with using functions as first-class objects. I had thought that C# lacked this feature, but then I heard about `Func` and `Action` and `delegate`, which I think are pretty awesomesauce.

For example, you can declare a `Func` that concatenates two strings and puts a space between them like this:

```
Func<string, string, string> concat = (a,b) => a + " " + b;
```

I noticed that when you type

```
Func<
```

the IntelliSense shows that it has 17 overloads:

```
delegate System.Func<out TResult>
delegate System.Func<in T, out TResult>
delegate System.Func<in T1, in T2, out TResult>
...snip...
delegate System.Func<in T1, in T2, in T3, in T4, in T5, in T6, in T7, in T8, in T9, in T10, in T11, in T12, in T13, in T14, in T15, in T16, out TResult>
```

That made me laugh. I looked at the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd402862.aspx#Y163) for `Func` and laughed again. This made me try to declare a `Func` with 17 arguments. It causes an error (`Using the generic type 'System.Func<TResult>' requires 1 type arguments`).

I can agree that it's probably not a good idea to have a `Func` that accepts more than 16 arguments. Even so, this seems like a kludgy way for `Func` to be implemented. It requires 17 trivially different overloads to be documented. This is all it really should need to know: the last type parameter is the return type, and all the type parameters before it are the argument types.

So what could I do if I wanted to create a `Func` with more than 16 parameters? Why is there a limit anyway? Why can't C# just let you declare a `Func` with an arbitrary number of arguments?

Comment: I would imagine because if you tried to use `params` the return type would be interpreted as an argument type. But, I never understood why it couldn't be `Func<out return, ...>` (since you declare a function with prototype (having return type) then arguments (e.g. `void Foo(a, b, c)`))

Comment: It is just a simple declaration.  The .NET designers got tired after 16.  If you need more than just declare your own Func<>.

Comment: @HansPassant The point is, why do they even have to keep adding overloads until they get tired of it? Why can't they just have a more general way to handle it, with one `out TResult` and `in T` 0 or more times?

Comment: Not sure why you think that's possible in C#.  It isn't.  They are *not* overloads, they are distinct delegate types that have nothing in common other than their name.

Comment: @HansPassant Er, why shouldn't it be possible? If you can have a `params` object to make a method that accepts an arbitrary number of arguments, why can't you use something similar to make this `Func` thing less ridiculous?

Comment: This isn't like `params` at all, the argument types are all different.

Comment: But why 16 ? I'm curious to know why it ended up with 16 parameters ? What made them to decide the number 16 ?

Comment: @Praveen In programming related things it's common to choose a power of 2. I guess they decided 8 was too low a limit and 16 was a reasonable upper limit.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're hoping for something like [variadic type arguments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template) which C# lacks. C# requires the arity of generic types to be fixed, therefore the heinous proliferation of `Func`, `Action`, and `Tuple` types.

If you're language shopping, this feature was added in C++11, but you should probably just use jQuery. :-)

Comment: I'd love to se how you would make a variadic verson of `Tuple`!

Comment: @Gabe: See the Wikipedia article I linked for the C++ syntax. I can imagine something like this in C#: `class Foo<T[]> { }` (accepts an array of types).

Comment: @Gabe: Even if C# gets variadic template it simply lacks the optimization facilities for it. It won't inline functions that take classes as arguments so when you try to construct a tuple with 16 argument you will get 32 function calls while c++ would inline this to 0 function calls at all.

Comment: @Daniel: you are wrong. `<T[]>` accepts an array of type T, not an array of types.

Comment: @Dani: I agree this is too deep of a language feature to ever be appended to C#. I think, as Carsten mentioned, there are better alternatives to achieving this on .NET -- currying is one.

Comment: I *knew* I should have just stuck with jQuery!

Comment: @Dani: I made up that syntax and I say it's an array of types. This is how I intend for it to work: `var foo = new Foo<new[] {int, string, double}>()` I hope you like it.

Comment: @Daniel: it doesn't matter if its nice or not, since it's ambiguous with an existing syntax, it just can't happen.

Comment: @Dani: It's not ambiguous in a context sensitive grammar such as C#'s, especially since nothing remotely similar is allowed within a type arg list. But, I'm not proposing new syntax anyway, only imagining...as I said.

Comment: @Dani: C# doesn't have any template facilities. Presumably if they added templates and variadic templates, why wouldn't they add the optimization features? The really big question, though, is how you would create the property names `Item9`, `Item10`, etc.

Comment: @Gabe, they can't because of the structure of the clr beneath it.

Answer (score 20):

You can just define any delegate you need. So a `Func` with 20 parameters would be defined like this:

```
public delegate R Func<
    P0, P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7, P8, P9,
    P10, P11, P12, P13, P14, P15, P16, P17, P18, P19, R>(
        P0 p0, P1 p1, P2 p2, P3 p3, P4 p4,
        P5 p5, P6 p6, P7 p7, P8 p8, P9 p9,
        P10 p10, P11 p11, P12 p12, P13 p13, P14 p14,
        P15 p15, P16 p16, P17 p17, P18 p18, P19 p19);
```

You could then use it like this:

```
Func<
        int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int,
        int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int> f = (
            p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10,
            p11, p12, p13, p14, p15, p16, p17, p18, p19) =>
                p0 + p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + p5 + p6 + p7 + p8 + p9 + p10
                    + p11 + p12 + p13 + p14 + p15 + p16 + p17 + p18 + p19;

var r = f(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
```

C# also lets you use lambda syntax on any delegate, so you could also do this:

```
public delegate R ArrayFunc<P, R>(params P[] parameters);
```

And then use it like so:

```
ArrayFunc<int, int> af = ps => ps.Sum();

var ar = af(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
```

It's a very flexible and powerful feature of the language.

Comment: I think the OP wants to know why these variations are needed in the first place. Showing him that you can proliferate them further doesn't address that.

Comment: @Daniel - The OP asked how he could create a delegate with more than 16 parameters and why couldn't he declare a delegate with a variable number of parameters. I've shown him how to do both of those. Other than that there is no reason other than an arbitrary choice as to why the framework stopped at 16. In .NET 2.0 `Func` only had four parameters.

Answer (score 7):

I think I understand - what you can do with JavaScript and functions (arguments) is preaty neat but it's also not statically typed.

But please note that you never need more than one argument in functional programming anyway. You can chain as much argument as you like by returning another function (this is a common trait in FP and heavaly used with curring a technique also avaiable in JS but only with bending the system a bit).

Of course this is ackward in C#:

```
Func<A1,Func<A2,Func<A3,...<Func<An,Result>>...> 
  x1 =>
    (x2 => 
      (x3 => 
        ... 
          (xn => 
              { /*return soomething */ }
  ))...);
```

but this is what F# is for ;) and of course you should never make a function with more than a few arguments (way below 16!) anyhow.

Comment: I agree: _"this is what F# is for"_

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own delegate with more than 16 arguments. Or you can use [`Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, TRest>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383325.aspx) (or any other data structure) as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`Why is there a limit anyway?`

There is opinion that function probably should not have more than 3 arguments. If it has more, it becomes increasingly harder to understand. Of course this may not be the reason why it is this way in C#, but this limitation may not be such a bad thing after all.

I would argue that even this limit of 16 is way too much and is encouraging bad design choices already.

Comment: Exactly, __Long Parameter List__ is one of the __Bloaters__ in code smells that must be refactored to remove some parameters from method. As you said, 16 is too much already.

Answer (score 1):

System.Func delegates are probably there thanks to the BCL team.. who realised including a finite number of predefined generic delegates would be handy (and even required for a lot of situations).

To do what you say.. i.e. unlimited number of generic parameters for a Func delegate would require a language change.. the responsiblity would lie with both c# and vb.net teams (and the others probably) to change the language to allow this.

Maybe, at some point, if the benefit of this feature outweighs the cost of predefining a handful of Func delegates and this is more important than other language changes (and that it isn't a breaking change) the relevent teams my implement unlimited generic parameters.. might not be for a while though!