# xamarin.android binding More than 16 parameters were found

Tags: android, xamarin, binding, xamarin.android

Binding project here:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiLsd2NKfovHm-sbwI-iFUTFI1Z-HQ

After use vs to build it, it will show the error:

More than 16 parameters were found, which goes beyond the maximum number of parameters...

build output here:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>JARTOXML : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning : ignoring option UseSplitVerifier; support was removed in 8.0
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8D00: More than 16 parameters were found, which goes beyond the maximum number of parameters. (in method Init in managed type Com.Baidu.Platform.Comjni.Map.Basemap.JNIBaseMap)
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8103: Class Com.Baidu.Mapapi.Map.WeightedLatLng has invalid base type com.baidu.mapapi.map.l.a.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8801: Invalid parameter type java.util.Collection<com.baidu.mapapi.map.WeightedLatLng> in method WeightedData in managed type Com.Baidu.Mapapi.Map.HeatMap.Builder.
1>D:\TempApps\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Baidu.Platform.Comapi.Map.E.cs(1274,19,1274,30): error CS0111: Type 'E' already defines a member called 'GetCHandler' with the same parameter types
1>D:\TempApps\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Baidu.Platform.Comapi.Map.E.cs(1281,15,1281,18): error CS0111: Type 'E' already defines a member called 'n_C' with the same parameter types
1>D:\TempApps\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Baidu.Platform.Comapi.Map.E.cs(1291,30,1291,31): error CS0111: Type 'E' already defines a member called 'C' with the same parameter types
1>D:\TempApps\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Baidu.Platform.Comapi.Map.E.cs(1378,19,1378,30): error CS0111: Type 'E' already defines a member called 'GetDHandler' with the same parameter types
1>D:\TempApps\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Baidu.Platform.Comapi.Map.E.cs(1385,15,1385,18): error CS0111: Type 'E' already defines a member called 'n_D' with the same parameter types
1>D:\TempApps\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Baidu.Platform.Comapi.Map.E.cs(1395,30,1395,31): error CS0111: Type 'E' already defines a member called 'D' with the same parameter types
1>D:\TempApps\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Baidu.Platform.Comapi.Map.E.cs(1552,19,1552,30): error CS0111: Type 'E' already defines a member called 'GetGHandler' with the same parameter types
1>D:\TempApps\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Baidu.Platform.Comapi.Map.E.cs(1559,15,1559,18): error CS0111: Type 'E' already defines a member called 'n_G' with the same parameter types
1>D:\TempApps\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Baidu.Platform.Comapi.Map.E.cs(1569,30,1569,31): error CS0111: Type 'E' already defines a member called 'G' with the same parameter types
1>D:\TempApps\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Baidu.Platform.Comapi.Map.E.cs(1620,19,1620,30): error CS0111: Type 'E' already defines a member called 'GetHHandler' with the same parameter types
1>D:\TempApps\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Baidu.Platform.Comapi.Map.E.cs(1627,17,1627,20): error CS0111: Type 'E' already defines a member called 'n_H' with the same parameter types
1>D:\TempApps\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Baidu.Platform.Comapi.Map.E.cs(1637,32,1637,33): error CS0111: Type 'E' already defines a member called 'H' with the same parameter types
1>D:\TempApps\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Baidu.Platform.Comapi.Map.E.cs(1688,19,1688,30): error CS0111: Type 'E' already defines a member called 'GetIHandler' with the same parameter types
1>D:\TempApps\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Baidu.Platform.Comapi.Map.E.cs(1695,15,1695,18): error CS0111: Type 'E' already defines a member called 'n_I' with the same parameter types
1>D:\TempApps\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Baidu.Platform.Comapi.Map.E.cs(1705,30,1705,31): error CS0111: Type 'E' already defines a member called 'I' with the same parameter types
1>D:\TempApps\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Baidu.Platform.Comapi.Map.E.cs(1756,19,1756,30): error CS0111: Type 'E' already defines a member called 'GetJHandler' with the same parameter types
1>D:\TempApps\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Baidu.Platform.Comapi.Map.E.cs(1763,15,1763,18): error CS0111: Type 'E' already defines a member called 'n_J' with the same parameter types
1>D:\TempApps\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\BaiduLBSAndroidSDKBindingV_4_3_2\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Baidu.Platform.Comapi.Map.E.cs(1773,30,1773,31): error CS0111: Type 'E' already defines a member called 'J' with the same parameter types
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the correct approach in this situation is to create a wrapper jar in Android Studio that you can then bind to which has less than 16 parameters. 16 parameters already has enough code smell as it is. The binding generator actually validates against this:

https://github.com/xamarin/java.interop/blob/master/tools/generator/MethodBase.cs#L194-L196

The limit I believe comes from Func and Action delegates

[Why don't Funcs accept more than 16 arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564027/why-dont-funcs-accept-more-than-16-arguments)

i.e.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd402862(v=vs.110).aspx

Another approach would be to directly work with the JNI:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/working_with_jni/

EX:

https://gist.github.com/mattleibow/2a7379294b8d59b6726891412b58445c

https://gist.github.com/mattleibow/f1cef8feed89f5d540b4d31cfc36b259

Comment: hello,I think your answer will resolve this error only.But after I do this,I also want use the wrapped jar's methods in the new jar.So,there has some way to do this?